# Replacing a value in a column- Snowflake (SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm extracting a number from a string using the following code:

```
regexp_substr(data, '\\d+\.\\d+') AS Age
```

Where the value is 0 (within the string), I'm getting a null value. Is there any way to correct this within the wider query, so all the nulls are replaced with 0s?

Comment: What are some sample strings that have values which you're not extracting as expected?

Comment: Note `\d+.\d+` means "one ore more digits followed by any character followed by one or more digits.  `0` does not match that pattern

Comment: @Kurt know any way to expand it to include 0?

Comment: what are all the valid numbers you're trying to capture?  why do you have the dot in the middle?

Comment: @kurt only the 0s are missing. Other than that, seems to be working.

Comment: as-is your pattern can only match strings which are at least three characters, and the middle one doesn't even have to be a digit.

Comment: @kurt just any number (including 0). The columns pertain to ages of newbuild houses (rounded down) to the nearest year.

Comment: to match any integer of any size without any punctuation in it would just be `\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be helpful if you have shared your sample data, but not sure if below helps:

```
select 
    regexp_substr(column1, '\\d+(\.?\\d+)?')
from values 
    ('test0me'),
    ('234.234'),
    ('test my age 25.')
;

+------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMN1, '\\D+(\.?\\D+)?') |
|------------------------------------------|
| 0                                        |
| 234.234                                  |
| 25                                       |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Pretty similar to what @kurt suggested, but without the leading "?:".

Answer (score 0):

Note `\d+.\d+` means "one ore more digits followed by *any* character followed by one or more digits.  This pattern requires at least 3 characters to match, and the middle one doesn't even have to be a digit.

0 does not match that pattern.  To match 0 or 42 or 1000000, i.e. any integer that is merely a string of digits, you only need `\d+`

10.5 does not match this pattern, however, so if you need to also capture decimal values, you will need something more complex that handles digits followed by an optional decimal point and more digits:

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

This pattern will match 0, 0.0, 42, 98.6, etc.

Comment: I got this error: Invalid regular expression: 'd+(?:.d+)?', no argument for repetition operator: ?

Comment: maybe snowflake doesn't support the (?:....) group match

Comment: maybe try something a little more brute force like `coalesce(regexp_substr(data, '\d+\.\d+'), regexp_substr(data, '\d+'), 0)`